# Examine whether $\{a_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence where $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Examine whether $\{a_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence where $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2n}$

Attempt: If $m>n$ where $m, n$ are natural numbers,

$|a_m-a_n|=|(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2m})-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2n})|=|\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\cdots +\frac{1}{2m}|=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\cdots +\frac{1}{2m}>\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$

Is the steps correct? Then what to do. Please help.

Comment: Your last step is strange. Why do you think $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}+\dots+\frac{1}{2m}<\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$? It is obviously greater.

Comment: @almagest Thanks. I am correcting.

Comment: The trick here is not obvious, but fairly well-known. Consider $\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\frac{1}{2^n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Each term is at least as big as the last one, and there are $2^n$ terms, so their sum is at least $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @almagest Would you want to suggest $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\cdots +\frac{1}{2m}>1/2$, if so would you suggest specific steps to prove that for this particular problem.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/(2k) = \infty$ implies $a_n \to \infty.$ Can an unbounded sequence be Cauchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$|a_m - a_n| = \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{2k} > \frac{m-n}{2m} > \frac{1}{2}(1 - n/m).$$

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can choose $m > 2n$ and find

$$|a_m - a_n| > \frac1{4}.$$

Thus, it is not the case that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $|a_m-a_n| < \epsilon$ for all $m > n > N$

Comment: $|a_m - a_n|  > \frac{1}{2}(1 - n/m)$ understood. But how to say $|a_m - a_n|  > \epsilon$  ?

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: Ok, nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1942348: You're welcome.